# Spark EMR SpringBoot Application not exiting

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am running My Spark SpringBoot Application on EMR and i am submitting these jobs (as steps) programatically. Everything is running fine except once the Spark Application completes its tasks it is not exiting. They are just sitting there running and not doing any thing there by causing all the subsequent submissions in the "Pending" state.

This is what i have in the main method of CommandLineRunner

```html
public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("STARTING THE APPLICATION");
        logger.info(".run() : No.of arguments ={}",args.length);
        Arrays.stream(args).forEach(arg->{
            logger.info(".main() : Argument={}",arg);
        });
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ConsoleApplication.class, args);
        context.close();
        logger.info("APPLICATION FINISHED");
    }
```

I cannot call System.exit(0) as per Spark Documentation.

By the way I am closing/stopping the JavaSparkContext and sparkSession at the end of the run method which is invoked from main.

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 0):

Using System.exit(0) seems to be the only option that is working.

Even though it is clearly specified not to use this while working in yarn cluster mode. For EMR everything is working as expected after calling it at the end of main method.